# The function evaluation requires all threads to run

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an `ASP.Net` `MVC 5` application, I want to run a raw query with `Entityframe work`

when I run my code I get bellow error:

> The function evaluation requires all threads to run

my code:

```
         using (var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            //var blogs = context.MySupportContext.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Supports").ToList();
            string myQuery = "Select id, FullName, sum(mins) as Mins from (Select t.id, FullName, NumberOfSupports* st.Minutes as mins from(Select st.Id, st.FullName, count(s.Id) as NumberOfSupports, s.SupportTypeId from SupportTeams stINNER JOIN Supports s on s.ResponsibleId = st.Idgroup by st.id, st.FullName, s.SupportTypeId) t inner join SupportTypes st on st.id = t.SupportTypeId) t group by id, FullName ";


            var blogs = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(myQuery);


            string qString= string.Empty;

            if (blogs != null)
            {
                qString= blogs.ToString();
            }
        }
```